# How can I populate a single attribute in linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ query which retrieves values from 2 tables as such:

```
    Dim query =  From t1 In context.table1
                 Join t2 In context.table2
                 On t1.ID Equals t2.ID
                 Select t1, t2
```

`table1` has an unmapped property of type `table2`, which I would like to populate using the selected `t2` value.

I've tried using the following:

```
For Each val In query.AsEnumerable() 
    val.t1.t2property = val.t2
Next
```

When I run the code, the `t2property` is not being populated (presumably because the query hasn't loaded due to lazy loading (feel free to correct me here)).

The added complexity is that I have to use this query as a source column in another query to the database.

Is there a way to populate the unmapped `t2property` from the `select` in the initial query?

Or is there something I can do to assign the `val.t1.t2property = val.t2`?

Comment: If you are using a database, do you need to `context.SubmitChanges()` to update the database? If you are using EF, your `t2property` should already contain the correct `t2` and handle the join for you.

Comment: @NetMage The tables I'm using are for informational purposes only.  The intent is to allow the application to do some calculations and then put the calculated info into different tables in the db.  I'm using EF, but the t2property isn't mapped to the database (it's been added after the fact into the table model), so it isn't populated by the query.  So, the t2property ends up being empty and t2 is populated with the desired value.

Comment: How do you know the `t2property` isn't populated? What do you do to acess `t2property` after the `for each` loop?

Comment: Because after the loop I use the query in another query(query2), and when I look at the results from query2, the t2property is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a variable a LINQ query, the variable is not assigned the results of the query but a representation of the query that can be executed later. When you do something that causes the query to be executed, the objects returned from the query are instantiated from the database and created in memory.

When you do the `For Each` loop over the `query` (the `AsEnumerable()` does nothing useful here), the query is executed, objects for `table1` and `table2` are created, and anonymous objects are created from those containing `t1` and `t2`.

After you exit the `For Each` loop, all those objects are thrown away, and the next time you execute `query`, new data is pulled from the database and new objects created.

If you need to hold onto and modify or query the objects in memory, you need to change the type of `query` to something that will hold the objects. Typically that will be an `Array` or `List`, in general, `ToList` is the better option.

```
Dim query = (From t1 In table1
             Join t2 In table2 On t1.ID Equals t2.ID
             Select t1, t2).ToList()

For Each val In query
    val.t1.t2property = val.t2
Next
```